# Qiskit experiments state tomography maximum allowed dimension exceeded for pulse gates

Tags: qiskit, state-tomography, qiskit-runtime

I'm trying to run state tomography on a custom pulse gate (currently just a CR(pi/4) pulse) and any attempt to run it on an IBM backend gives a maximum allowed dimension exceeded error. The code runs fine for any standard gates on the backend.

All the potentially relevant code is:

```
from qiskit_experiments.library import StateTomography
from qiskit import pulse

service = QiskitRuntimeService()
backend = service.get_backend(name='ibm_kyoto')

#Extracts the CR(pi/4) pulse
from qiskit.pulse import Play

backend_defaults = backend.defaults()
inst_sched_map = backend_defaults.instruction_schedule_map 
cr_pulse = inst_sched_map.get('ecr', (1,0)).filter(channels = [ControlChannel(1)], instruction_types=[Play]).instructions[0][1].pulse

with pulse.build(backend, name="Default CR") as cr_sched_default:
        pulse.play(cr_pulse, ControlChannel(1))


from qiskit.circuit import Gate
from qiskit.pulse import builder
from qiskit.transpiler import InstructionProperties

# Makes the circuit, turns it into a schedule
circ = QuantumCircuit(4)
custom_gate = Gate('cr', num_qubits=2, params=[])
circ.add_calibration('cr', [0,1], cr_sched_default)
circ.append(custom_gate, [0,1])


backend.target.add_instruction(
    custom_gate, 
    {(0,1): InstructionProperties(calibration=cr_sched_default)},
)
circ = transpile(circ, backend)

#runs the state tomography and returns the results
from qiskit_ibm_provider import IBMProvider

provider = IBMProvider()
backend = provider.get_backend(name='ibm_kyoto')

with backend.open_session() as session:
    qstexp = StateTomography(circ, measurement_indices=[0,1])
    qstdata = qstexp.run(backend).block_for_results()

    for result in qstdata.analysis_results():
        print(result)
    state_result = qstdata.analysis_results("state")
    print(state_result.value)
```

Much of the code comes from the qiskit textbook: https://github.com/Qiskit/textbook/blob/main/notebooks/quantum-hardware-pulses/hamiltonian-tomography.ipynb

The error is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[97], line 10
      6 backend = provider.get_backend(name='ibm_kyoto')
      9 with backend.open_session() as session:
---> 10     qstexp = StateTomography(circ, measurement_indices=[0,1])
     11     qstdata = qstexp.run(backend).block_for_results()
     13     for result in qstdata.analysis_results():

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\qiskit_experiments\warnings.py:169, in deprecate_arguments.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    160 if kwargs:
    161     _rename_kwargs(
    162         args[0].__class__.__name__ + "." + func.__name__,
    163         kwargs,
   (...)
    167         stacklevel,
    168     )
--> 169 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\qiskit_experiments\library\tomography\qst_experiment.py:122, in StateTomography.__init__(self, circuit, backend, physical_qubits, measurement_basis, measurement_indices, basis_indices, conditional_circuit_clbits, analysis, target)
    120 if isinstance(self.analysis, TomographyAnalysis):
    121     if target == "default":
--> 122         target = self._target_quantum_state()
    123     self.analysis.set_options(target=target)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\qiskit_experiments\library\tomography\qst_experiment.py:138, in StateTomography._target_quantum_state(self)
    136         state = DensityMatrix(circuit)
    137     else:
--> 138         state = Statevector(circuit)
    139 except QiskitError:
    140     # Circuit couldn't be simulated
    141     return None

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\qiskit\quantum_info\states\statevector.py:91, in Statevector.__init__(self, data, dims)
     89     self._data = np.ravel(data.data)
     90 elif isinstance(data, (QuantumCircuit, Instruction)):
---> 91     self._data = Statevector.from_instruction(data).data
     92 else:
     93     raise QiskitError("Invalid input data format for Statevector")

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\qiskit\quantum_info\states\statevector.py:765, in Statevector.from_instruction(cls, instruction)
    763     instruction = instruction.to_instruction()
    764 # Initialize an the statevector in the all |0> state
--> 765 init = np.zeros(2**instruction.num_qubits, dtype=complex)
    766 init[0] = 1.0
    767 vec = Statevector(init, dims=instruction.num_qubits * (2,))

ValueError: Maximum allowed dimension exceeded
```

Does anyone know what am I missing?